# 1D and 2D partitioning in Matrix operations

Tags: parallel-processing, hpc

Which is better between 1D and 2D partitioning in matrix operations and how is it better?
I have looked for how both partitions work but still couldn’t find which one is better. 
Can anyone please help me..

Comment: In case of multiplication of matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For distributed computation of sparse matrices, 2D partitioning is shown to be more scalable than 1D partitioning [1]. Having `p` processes, if you create a two dimensional grid of `p^2` tiles, a 2D partitioning such as 2D-cyclic limits the communication of a row/column group of tiles to `sqrt(p)` processes whereas, e.g., 1D-column has to communicate with `p` processes for row group communication and no other process for column group communication. Therefore, 1D-column speedup is bound to a larger communication time which is a factor of `p`.

[1] Buluc, Aydin, and John R. Gilbert. Linear algebraic primitives for parallel computing on large graphs. University of California, Santa Barbara, 2010.